# Find employees who have worked on at least 2 projects

Tags: mysql, sql, popsql

I need to make basically this **without** using the "Group by"

```
SELECT  idEmploye , COUNT(*) AS nbrProjet
FROM ressourcesprojet_ 
GROUP BY idEmploye 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

My Database code for creating it : https://sourceb.in/JePvGUccpU

Things i tried :

```
SELECT e.idEtape, e.idProjet, e.dateDebut, e.dateFin 
FROM (
    SELECT idProjet, dateDebut, dateFin 
    FROM Projet) AS p 
RIGHT JOIN EtapexProjet AS e 
    ON e.dateDebut > p.dateDebut AND e.dateFin > p.dateFin 
ORDER BY p.idProjet;
```

```
SELECT  E.idEmploye ,
    (SELECT COUNT(idProjet) 
     FROM ressourcesprojet_ 
     Where E.idEmploye = idEmploye) AS nbrProjet 
From employe_ E;
```

```
SELECT idEmploye 
FROM ressourcesprojet_ WHERE 1 < (
    SELECT COUNT(idProjet) 
    FROM ressourcesprojet_ 
    where idEmploye = idEmploye);
```

I just can't wrap my head around it

Comment: Why do you have to do it without `GROUP BY`?

Comment: The last attempt uses `GROUP BY`.

Comment: It's part of the excercise, i guess i need to create a artificial "group by"?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you want, would affect if this is usable. Here is an example, which technically doesn't use the grouping, but if you added any other columns would easily require it:

```
DECLARE @test2 TABLE (num INT)

INSERT INTO @test2 VALUES (1), (2), (3), (2), (4)

SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM @Test2 t
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Test2 it WHERE it.num = t.num) > 1
```

P.S - I have to assume this is either a puzzle or test question

Alternative Edit:

```
DECLARE @test2 TABLE (id INT, num INT)

INSERT INTO @test2 VALUES (1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 2), (3, 4)

SELECT *
FROM @Test2 t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @Test2 it WHERE it.id = t.id AND it.num <> t.num)
```

This results in the following being returned:

```
id, num
1, 1
```

Comment: Oh! i kinda see the logic. 
Hmm, I see. I think I was going further than I had to.
Like, I thought the question is how to get the largest "idEtapes".
In other words, like "max()" that I had to apply, but only on the project in question and in the subquery. I was also reading something about "EXISTS" but... i think juste "DISTINCT" is way... easy xD?

Comment: You could use a not exists and join on the val. I'll write an example in a minute.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p1.idEmploye
FROM RessourcesProjet_ AS p1
JOIN RessourcesProjet_ AS p2 ON p1.idEmploye = p2.idEmploye AND p1.idProjet != p2.idProjet
```

This joins the `RessourcesProjet_` with itself to find all pairs of rows with the same employee and different projects, so this will find anyone who has worked on more than one project.

Then it uses `DISTINCT` so we don't see all the duplications.

This doesn't generalize easily to "at least N" like the methods that use `COUNT()` do. It needs to self-join N copies of the table, and all the `ON` clauses will need to check that the project isn't in any of the previous copies of the table.

Comment: I don't think you need the and condition if your using the distinct in this scenario

Comment: I think I still need some practice with SQL logic. The solutions I had thought of were off the mark. Maybe because it's in English that I understand less well xD

But in any case, thank you! It also helps me to realize where I have gaps in my understanding

Comment: @Monofuse It's needed because each row will join with itself, you need to filter those out.

Comment: My bad I forgot about the where > 1 condition